# Is it possible to update a file in all branches in the git version control?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I wrote a simple CMS years ago and now I have multiple branches for this CMS and I want to update a file that used from all branches and is not change since from version 1.

So how can I update this file and tell to all branches to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your priorities.

Since the file has never changed before, the commit in which it was first added should be a suitable "common root" at which you could create a new branch to apply the change; and then merge it to all branches.  This approach would best reflect the true history of the project.

Of course the down-side is that it's a lot of merge operations.  If there are a lot of branches, it could be tedious to apply all the merges (though you could automate it, counting on the idea that you're modifying a file that never changed so you shouldn't get any conflicts).  Also those merges are added to each branch's history.  To me that's not a bad thing - it's again the accurate history - but some people do dislike "complex" commit topology; so it's something you might choose to consider.

The other option would be to rewrite the history.  This has several potential down-sides.  All of your commit ID values would change.  If you use the commit ID's in any sort of tool or documentation, it could be an issue.  And if there are other users with clones of the repo, they would have to recover from essentially a mass of "upstream rebase"-like conditions.  Plus your rewritten history would not reflect what the code really looked like at any point in history.  But if you don't care about those things, then this is easier to do and avoids changing the commit topology.

So the easiest way to do that would be with `filter-branch`.

```
git filter-branch tree-filter='cp /some/path/to/new/version worktree/path/to/old/version' -- --all
```

You could probably work out a way to use the `index-filter` instead of `tree-filter`, which would be faster - but not quite as easy.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a new branch to make the changes to your file. Then you can merge that branch into all the other branches. This will add all changes from the new branch to each branch where you merge it.

Comment: This branch should start from the oldest common commit.